# Docker: share prepopulated container folder with host, using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an image (a web app) that contains a codebase in `var/www/html`. When the container starts it further generates some artifacts (config files) in `var/www/html` as part of its start up process. I would like to be able to edit those file via the host file system, while keeping them alive in the container.

**Update:** clarified that the image already contain files in the folder.

I know it is possible to map (e.g. sync) a host folder to a container folder via a *shared volume*, e.g. `docker run -d -v path/on/host:path/on/container myimage`. However, this will effectively override the contents of the container folder with whatever exists in the host folder. I would like to retain the files generated by the container.

I also know it is possible to copy files out of the container with `docker cp <container id>:path/on/container path/on/host`, which might be an intermediary step, but I just can't find a full example on how to accomplish what I want.

Preferably I would like to do it all in a single docker-compose file because other containers are involved in my setup (e.g. a mysql container). However, a sequence of docker commands would also do.

Comment: If these files are generated as part of the start-up process, then it seems like mounting a host directory over the container contents, then running the generation sequence, achieves what you want?

Comment: @DavidMaze: yes, that would be a good solution. Only, in my case, the start-up process is built-in into the image I'm using (in its Dockerfile it fetches a codebase from github to `/var/www/html` and it has an entrypoint.sh that sets it up). If I mount a host directory `A` to `/var/www/html` in docker-compose, the contents of the directory will be replaced by the contents of `A`, so the entrypoint.sh will fail. I guess I could change the Dockerfile and make my own image, but I would rather handle it all in a docker-compose file. Btw: I'm new to Docker.

Comment: @DavidMaze: ... I updated my question to clarify my situation.